# Gruntjs: что это и с чем его едят?

Tags: node.js, json, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток! Кто знаком как-либо с `gruntjs`? Подскажите, есть ли какая литература или документация на русском, буду благодарен любой информации.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=gruntjs&oq=gruntjs&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l2j69i60.2491j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lr=lang_ru&newwindow=1&q=gruntjs&safe=off&tbs=lr:lang_1ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста.

- [Grunt, инструмент для сборки javascript проектов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148274/)
- [GRUNT. The JavaScript Task Runner](http://www.slideshare.net/FDConf/javascript-grunt)
- [Делаем жизнь проще, GruntJS (для новичков)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/177395/)